# Android Studio ( Ubuntu )

Tags: android, intellij-idea

My android studio suddenly has changed the editor font to enormous.
I'm on Ubuntu, changing font size in settings (of android studio) doesn't
change the font. What can I do? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: It happens to me after I used Open JDK, I switched to Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the system font with [UnityTweakTool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/).